# How to list only file name?

Tags: vb.net

I have program to find files in a directory and list them in a listbox, but the following code I'm using adds the full path for the file found.

Is there something I'm missing to make it only add the file name and not the full path?

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\" & Details.IDL.Text) Then
    For Each FoundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\" & Details.IDL.Text)
        ListBox.Items.Add(FoundFile)
    Next
Else
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\" & Details.IDL.Text)
End If
```

so to fix it i only had to put `ListBox.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(FoundFile))` instead of `ListBox.Items.Add(FoundFile)`

Comment: Assuming *VB.Net*: [Path.GetFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not directly related, but you see where you have repeated `My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\" & Details.IDL.Text` three times? It would be better to put that in a variable. Also, it would be better to use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) to put the parts of the path together as then you do not have to worry about the path separator character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example to list file name individually with `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`, along with the way you are using `GetFileName`.

```
Dim fileName As String = "C:\mydir\myfile.ext"
Dim pathname As String = "C:\mydir\"
Dim result As String

result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
Console.WriteLine("GetFileNameWithoutExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'", fileName, result)

result = Path.GetFileName(pathname)
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", pathname, result)
```